# What word refers to the structure of a sentence?

Tags: word-request

I am wondering what's the word that refers to the form, structure of a sentence? By form, I mean the number of predicates, the length, the subject, verb, object order, etc.

For example:

> This sentence has a complex ___; it contains several commas, several
>   vanity words like "therefrom" and "whereamong", and several verbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Most generally, *syntax*

Per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/syntax):

> **syntax** noun
>
> **1a** : the way in which linguistic elements (such as words) are put together to form constituents (such as phrases or clauses)
>
> **b** : the part of grammar dealing with this
>
> *Coming from a great distance and wholly unrelated to the Teutonic,
>   Latin and Slav languages that fence it in, Hungarian has remained
>   miraculously intact. Everything about the language is different, not
>   only the words themselves, but the way they are formed, the syntax and
>   grammar and above all the cast of mind that brought them into being.*
>
> — Patrick Leigh Fermor, Between the Woods and the Water, 1986
>
> *“I saw that she a cookie ate” is an example of incorrect syntax.*

**Sentence structure** is also used with this meaning (see [thefreedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sentence+structure)), but may also refer to the more specific [clausal structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure) of the sentence.

In your example, these might also be combined as **syntactic structure**, which is an unambiguous means of referring to the structure of a sentence as a whole, rather than its clausal configuration.